# 添付ファイル付きのメールを複数送信先に送りたい

Tags: monaca

monacaを使用して、アプリ内で画像ファイルを生成し、それを添付した状態でメーラーを起動するAndroidアプリを作成しています。

```
var extras = {};
extras[window.plugins.webintent.EXTRA_EMAIL] = "hoge@gmail.com";
extras[window.plugins.webintent.EXTRA_SUBJECT] = "タイトル";
extras[window.plugins.webintent.EXTRA_TEXT] = "本文";
extras[window.plugins.webintent.EXTRA_STREAM] = "file:///sdcard/" + fileName;
window.plugins.webintent.startActivity( {
    action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_SEND,
    type: 'text/plain',
    extras: extras
});
```

上記の方法で単一の送信先には送れるようになったのですが、送信先を複数持たせる必要が出てきました。

```
extras[window.plugins.webintent.EXTRA_BCC] = "fuga@gmail.com";
```

を試してみたのですが、BCCに追加されません。（メーラーは起動します）
また、EXTRA_CCも結果は同様です。

インテントをACTION_VIEWに変更し「mailto:」も試してみましたが、CC,BCCは設定できるものの、今度はファイルの添付方法がわかりません。
（attach、attachmentは試してみました）

送信先はBCCやCCに追加できるのがベストですが、TOに追加する形でもかまいません。
何か良い方法がありますでしょうか。

Comment: メールアドレスをカンマ区切りで列挙することにより、
複数送信先に対応することができました。
（セミコロン区切りしか試していませんでした・・・）

Gmailとdocomoメールで確認済みです。
他メーラーへの対応や、CC、BCCへの追加方法等、検証の余地は残りますが
とりあえずクローズさせて頂きます。

ご検討頂いた皆様ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決した場合、自分で解答を投稿し自分の投稿を承認してください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

メールアドレスをカンマ区切りで列挙することにより、
複数送信先に対応することができました。
（セミコロン区切りしか試していませんでした・・・）

Gmailとdocomoメールで確認済みです。
他メーラーへの対応や、CC、BCCへの追加方法等、検証の余地は残りますが
とりあえずクローズさせて頂きます。

ご検討頂いた皆様ありがとうございました。